# How to use PHP $_REQUEST

Tags: php

When submitting this form, is there any way to catch `$_GET['aa']` and `$_POST['aa']`, using only `$_REQUEST`?

```
<form action="abc.php?aa=1" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="aa" value="23" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: No. Why would this ever be a requirement?

Comment: if you are mentioning method as post , then why would you catch the value using request

Comment: What i can see is you are trying to pass **'aa=1'** using form action and again **'aa=23'** using the input type='text'. Can you clarify this?

Comment: The author is asking if a page named `abc.php?aa=1` can have passed $_POST['aa'] to it, so it would have both `$_GET['aa'] = 1;` and `$_POST['aa'] = 23;`

Answer (score 2):

`$_REQUEST` is an associative array that by default contains the contents of `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_COOKIE`.

If `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_COOKIE` all have the same parameter (i.e. 'aa' in your case ) one will override others and become the final result in `$_REQUEST`.

The decision on who should win depends on the [request_order](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.request-order) and [variable_order](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order) settings in the `php.ini` configuration file. The default is in the order of ENV, GET, POST, COOKIE and SERVER. So in your case, the `$_POST['aa']` will be the same as `$_REQUEST['aa']`.

Note that the default distribution `php.ini` files does not contain the 'C' for cookies, due to security concerns.That means if you also have a Cookie named 'aa', it might not end up in the `$_REQUEST` variable. It depends on the settings. This is good for security reasons and you don't want to change this default.

Answer (score 1):

`$_REQUEST` is the mixture of both `$_POST` and `$_GET`.It will give you both post and get variables.You can use `$_REQUEST` as like as `$_GET` and `$_POST` like

```
$_REQUEST['aa'];
```

But here If your `form type` is **post** then only use `$_POST` or if it is **get** type then use `$_GET`.

If you have both `post` and `get` params with same name and if you using `$_REQUEST` then it will take `POST` variable only.Because POST has the higher priority than GET.

Comment: If you look at the `action` attribute of the form, there is an HTTP GET parameter there.

Comment: If you have both post and get params with same name and if you using $_REQUEST then it will take POST variable only

Comment: Depends on the [variables_order](http://www.php.net/manual/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order) configuration item